# Python/R Exploratory Data Analysis for Classification

Tags: r, classification, python, exploratory-data-analysis

Are there preexisting functions in Python/R that create exploratory data analysis plots like the following: [image: Exploratory Data Analysis]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, the pairs() command can do this (check the Scatterplot Matrices plot ): http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/scatterplot.html

In python, check seaborn for the pairplot() and Pairgrid methods:
http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/axis_grids.html